# Confused about: RandomAccessFile.readFully(byte[] b)

Tags: java, byte, randomaccessfile

lets say byte[] b = 1024

```
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    data.readFully(b);
```

does the readFully() method increment by itself if it is put inside of a loop kind of like the nextLine() method? or will continue to read the same 1024 bytes over and over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes after reading the specified number of bytes the pointer will be moved.